# List.add not working on device but in editor

Tags: c#, ios, list, udp, multicast

Ahoi!

Im working on a Unity2d application to control multiple devices via UDP.
To check if all devices send a response upon receiving a command I try to log the messages into a List after checking if the message is already in said list via:

```
public void checkifinlist(string message)
{
//strip message for to last ip block
 cameraIP = message.Substring(0, message.IndexOf(" \n") + 1).Remove(0, PlayerPrefs.GetString("iproot").Length).Remove(3);
        containsItem = false;
//check if in list
        for (int I = 0; I < allRecieved.Count; I++)
        {
            if (allRecieved[I].ip == int.Parse(cameraIP))
            {
                containsItem = true;
            }
        }
//if not in list add to list
        if (containsItem == false)
        {
            messageEvent nme = new messageEvent();
            nme.ip = int.Parse(cameraIP);
            nme.delay = endTime - startTime;
            allRecieved.Add(nme);
            endTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
            Debug.Log(allRecieved.Count + ": " + nme.ip);
            CameraResponseCounter++;
    }
```

works nicely in the editor but not on my test device (iPhone 10, iOS 13).

In editor : the "CameraResponseCounter" runs up to the number of all devices. 
On device : -,,- to 1.

Does anybody know what causes this behavior?

Comment: I working on similar project.  The log file needs to be flushed to push all data.  The stream write uses timers a buffer size to put data into file and in Real time Applications the data may not get moved.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the response! My problem is that I resend the commands each 5x to make sure every device receives them. I could simply count the messages, but would have an unreliable count of all responses. Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I think you may have a cross threading issue and using INVOKE may help.                   BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                    {
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    });

Comment: Ok, thanks! Will try!

Comment: If you have read/write from different threads you may need a lock.  It is possible for an event to occur between the log entry and the counter increment.